# I am unable to run rvm commands inside any rails_app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Everything works fine at home directory

```
phorekka@phorekka:~$ rvm -v
rvm 1.27.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis ><mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

but whenever i try to run the commands inside rails_project directory..
  I get this message

```
phorekka@phorekka:~/rails_project/sample_app3$ rvm get head && rvm reload  
No command 'rvm' found, but there are 20 similar ones
```

so please help me out . I can't figure out whats's the problem.

Comment: What is the output of `which rvm` when ran from your home directory?

Comment: Does your project have a `.rvmrc`, a `.ruby-version` or a `.versions.conf` file?  Or does your Gemfile contain a Ruby comment (e.g. `#ruby=2.1.1`) or Ruby directive (e.g. ruby "2.1.1")?  If so, what are the contents of the file(s)?

Comment: Thanks a lot @MichaelGaskill and @ dre ...for your response.  I just removed the rvm completely and installed it again. Now it works fine .